# How to integrate python api request and response with javascript

Tags: javascript, python, html, api, file-upload

I have set of api's in server.py namely for file upload, pre-processing data for analytics etc. I want to integrate and make the api calls via the UI. I am not able to start even with the file upload since i am not able to interact with the API through my UI. Kindly help me in understanding how to integrate the UI with the API.

API is returning output in JSON file:

code snippet server.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_restplus import Resource, Api, fields, reqparse
import os
import pandas
import json
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
from waitress import serve
from werkzeug.datastructures import FileStorage
import parser
import uuid
import importlib
@app.route('/dashboard')
def dashboard():
return render_template('dashboard.html')
@api.route('/api/v1/fileupload')
class upload_file(Resource):
@api.expect(file_upload_model)
def post(self):
    try:
        requestid = uuid.uuid4().hex
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('file', type=FileStorage, location='files', 
        required=True)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        # checking if the file is present or not.
        #if 'file' not in request.files:
        #    return "No file found"
        file = args.get('file')

        #file = request.files['file']

        path = os.path.join(os.path.join(server_path, requestid + "\\" + 
        "rawdata"))
        if os.path.exists(path):
            pass
        else:
            os.makedirs(path)

        abs_path = path + "\\" + file.filename
        file.save(abs_path)
        return {"requestid": requestid, "upload_status": "success", 
        "location": abs_path}, 200
        except Exception as e:
        requestid = None
        return {"requestid": requestid, "upload_status": "failed::" + str(e) 
        , "location": ""}
```

code snippet for dashboard.html

```
<form class="navbar-brand" method="POST">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function checkfile(sender) {
            var validExts = new Array(".csv");
            var fileExt = sender.value;
            fileExt = fileExt.substring(fileExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
            if (validExts.indexOf(fileExt) < 0) {
                alert("Invalid file selected, please select only" +
                    validExts.toString() +"file");
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
    </script>
    <div>Select a file to Upload: <br>
        <input type="file" name="fileupload"
               value="fileupload" id="fileupload" onchange=checkfile(this) /> <br>
        <small>please select .csv file only</small>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be missing the entire part where you upload the file. This code should get you there.

- Removed your `checkfile` function, and used the `accept` attribute
- Added an event listener for the form submit and upload
- Prevent the page from redirecting, you can decide what to display
- The `output` div will show an upload status.

#### Solution

```js
var form = document.forms.namedItem("upload-form");

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  var data = new FormData(this);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open("POST", "/api/v1/fileupload", true);
  request.onload = function(e) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      output.innerHTML = "Uploaded!";
    } else {
      output.innerHTML = "Error " + request.status + " occurred when trying to upload your file.<br \/>";
    }
  };

  request.send(data);
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

```html
<form class="navbar-brand" name="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div>Select a file to Upload: <br>
      <input
        type="file"
        name="fileupload"
        id="fileupload"
        accept=".csv"
      /> <br>
      <small>please select .csv file only</small>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the above and now upon selecting file and clicking upload. Page just refreshes without giving success or error status code.  Please can you help with too.                                                                              Thanks,                                                                                        Monica C

Comment: Can you put your most recent code on jsFiddle and share the link?

Comment: Below is the curl command
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:5510/api/v1/fileupload \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'file=@C:\Users\sample data.csv'.              How do I get the above file object there or how can I call the file object in the above code

Comment: It’s not the request that’s causing the refresh, it’s a bug in your code, which is why I need to see it.

Comment: It's because your JavaScript is before your HTML, so it can't find the HTML elements to attach listeners to. You either have to put your JS at the very bottom, or wrap it with `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ \\ your code here })`

Comment: JavaScript isn't a compiled language, it's an interpreted language, meaning it runs as it's read in real time, and if your elements don't exist in the DOM when it runs, it just moves on and never comes back.